# How to set browser preference in PhantomJS using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is there any way to use browser preference like `"network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris"` in phantomJS.

Below is the syntax for selenium with firefox:

```
p_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
p_profile.set_preference("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "https://xx.com")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(p_profile)
driver.get("https://xx.com")
```

Is there any similar feature available in PhantomJS.

Comment: Are you asking how to generally setup preferences in PhantomJS through selenium or are you asking how the specific "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris" option can be achieved? There is no such thing as trusted-URIs in PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `desired_capabilities` keyword argument when you create `PhantomJS` object.

For example, to change User-Agent header:

```
from selenium import webdriver


cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()                            
cap['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'] = 'asdf'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=cap)
driver.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Check [`settings` - PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) for other available settings.

Comment: I tried that, but is there any option like dcap["network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris"] available in Phantom

Comment: I came here to +1 this, because ı wanted not to load images and this is a great solution, thanks.